# Access database relationships one-to-one and one-to-many

Tags: database, ms-access, one-to-many, entity-relationship, one-to-one

[image]

This relationship should be one-to-one because ONE phone number can be allocated only to ONE customer and ONE customer can have only ONE phone number (in this case)

How to do it right??
Any help appreciated

Comment: I *think* you need to put a unique constraint on the n_number in customer and make sure that n_number is primary in numbers.

Comment: Thankyou very much Mike Cheel........ its done...! Thumbs up

Comment: @MikeCheel post it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put a unique constraint on the n_number in customer and make sure that n_number is primary in numbers